# Selenium select button from popup window

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I am trying to select the confirmation box using Python and Selenium. I am able to click the 'Transfer' button then I am prompted with the following message "Are you sure you want to transfer the selected account items and permissions to Backup Backup (backup)?" Then there are two buttons 
1."Cancel" 
2."OK"

[Click transfer button to transfer account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74xFK.png)

When I get to this part, I am unable to get Selenium to go to the next step, which is clicking the "OK" button.

["OK" button to confirm account transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrf7E.png)

Below is the HTML.

```html
<div style="padding-top: 15px;">
<input id="submit_transfer" class="button" name="submit_transfer" onclick="return verifyTransfer('');" value="Transfer" type="submit"/>
<input id="do_transfer" name="do_transfer" value="0" type="hidden"/>
<input id="delete_user" name="delete_user" value="0" type="hidden"/>
<input id="cancel_transfer" class="button" name="cancel_transfer" value="Cancel" type="submit"/>
</div>
```

```
def transfer_account(drive):
    """

    :param drive: 
    :return: 
    """
    transfer_account_xpath = ".//*[@id='submit_transfer']"

    test = ".//*[@id='submit_transfer']"

    transfer_account_ = drive.find_element_by_xpath(transfer_account_xpath)
    transfer_account_.click()

    al = driver.switch_to.alert()
    print al.text

    time.sleep(3)

    # result = None
    # try:
    # except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    #     print 'error'
```

Comment: You have to change something called the "frame". I haven't used selenium in a long time, but from what i recall, if you go ahead and look deeply into the html of your website, you'll probably find different 'frames". I'm not sure how to do this, but i hope this nudges you in the right direction

Comment: @AbdulrahmanAttia , that's something that I haven't tried. I'll let you know if it helps.

Comment: Look at this answer. it shows you how to do it. [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39360384/how-to-switch-from-one-popup-to-another-popup-in-selenium-webdriver?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

```
   try:
    WebDriverWait(drive, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                    'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                    'confirmation popup to appear.')

    alert = drive.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
    print "alert accepted"
except TimeoutException:
    print "no alert"
```